# Correct XML representation of derived class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

So I have the following base class and derived classes:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Circle))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Square))]
public class Shape
{
    public int XPos { get; set; }
    public int YPos { get; set; }
}

public class Circle : Shape
{
   public int Radius { get; set; }
}

public class Square : Shape
{
    public int Side { get; set; }
}
```

How do I represent Circle and Square in a XML so that can be deserialized to a new object ?

I´m trying:

```
<Shape type="Circle">
   <Radius>10</Radius>
</Shape>
<Shape type="Square">
   <Side>20</Side>
</Shape>
```

and

```
<Circle>
   <Radius>10</Radius>
</Circle>
<Square>
   <Side>20</Side>
</Square>
```

but none of them is loading a Shape object with the current derived class (Square or Circle). The first option creates a Square object. The second creates no objects at all. I´m using C# MVC4.

**[EDIT - TEST CODE]**

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var shape = new Shape { XPos = 4, YPos = 5 };
        Console.WriteLine(Serialize(shape));
        Console.WriteLine();

        var circle = new Circle { XPos = 1, YPos = 2, Radius = 3 };
        Console.WriteLine(Serialize(circle));
        Console.WriteLine();

        var square = new Square { XPos = 2, YPos = 1, Side = 5 };

        var ser = Serialize(square);

        Console.WriteLine(square);

        Square sq = Deserialize(ser);

        Console.WriteLine(sq.Side);
    }

    public static string Serialize(Shape objectToSerialize)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Shape));
        StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, objectToSerialize);
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }

    public static Square Deserialize(string ser)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Square));

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(ser))
        {
            return (Square)(serializer.Deserialize(reader));
        }
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(Circle))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(Square))]
    public class Shape
    {
        public int XPos { get; set; }
        public int YPos { get; set; }
    }

    public class Circle : Shape
    {
       public int Radius { get; set; }
    }

    public class Square : Shape
    {
        public int Side { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods below will serialize and deserialize the shapes. The deserialize method is generic to allow for different shapes to be deserialized.

I've included examples of each object serialized as XML. Here is the [dot net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qCaXQ6) used to create the examples. It also shows how to deserialize the objects.

**Serialize**

```
public static string Serialize(Shape objectToSerialize)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Shape));
    StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();

    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, objectToSerialize);
    return textWriter.ToString();
}
```

**Deserialize**

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string xmlToDeserialize) where T : Shape
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Shape));

    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlToDeserialize)) {
         return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

**Example Shape XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Shape xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <XPos>4</XPos>
  <YPos>5</YPos>
</Shape>
```

**Example Circle XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Shape xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Circle">
  <XPos>1</XPos>
  <YPos>2</YPos>
  <Radius>3</Radius>
</Shape>
```

**Example Square XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Shape xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Square">
  <XPos>2</XPos>
  <YPos>1</YPos>
  <Side>5</Side>
</Shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will use `xsi:type` to declare the `Type`, e.g. `xsi:type="Circle"`

Example

```
<Shape xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="Circle">
  <XPos>1</XPos> 
  <YPos>2</YPos> 
  <Radius>3</Radius> 
</Shape>
```

My De/Serialize test code

```
var shape = new Circle { XPos = 1, YPos = 2, Radius = 3};
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Shape));
var xml = string.Empty;

using(var sw = new StringWriter())
{
    ser.Serialize(sw, shape);
    xml = sw.ToString();
}

using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var obj = ser.Deserialize(sr);
}
```

If you need an easy way to return the strong types you could add a generic method.

```
public T DeserializeShape<T>(string xml) where T : Shape
{
    var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Shape));
    using (var sr = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
    }
}

var circle = DeserializeShape<Circle>(xml);
var square = DeserializeShape<Square>(xml); // etc....
```

Comment: Sorry... I´m new to XMl... Why I need an external schema if the Shape object is defined in my namespace that parses the Xml ?

Comment: The XML Schema definition language (XSD) defines attributes for use in XML instance documents. in this case you are using the 'type' attribute

Comment: Check out my EDIT in the original post. The code is based on Harris suggestion.